# Query Multiple Resources From Tastypie API with Union?

Tags: django, angularjs, tastypie

Can I query multiple resources from a single Tastypie API call, with the results coming back as a `UNION` of results?

I have a single `input` field that I ask users to type their *name* or *employee id* into.  I would like to avoid splitting the field into two if possible, I want the input burden to be on the system and not the user.

I am wanting to pull data from two different resources.  A `Person` could be an `Employee` or a guest who doesn't work for the company.  An `Employee` is just that.

```
class EmployeeResource(ModelResource):
    '''
    Resource of all company employees
    '''
    class Meta:
        filtering = {
            "empid": ['exact', 'startswith']
        }
        resource_name = 'employee'
        queryset = Employee.objects.all()

class PersonResource(ModelResource):
    '''
    Resource of employees and guests who have visited the lab
    '''
    employee = fields.ForeignKey(EmployeeResource, 'empid', blank=True, null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'person'
        queryset = Person.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            "name": ['icontains'],
            "employee": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

I would like to set up a Tastypie resource query that will pull values from both tables, and ignore duplicates.

For example, when I query "Doe" it pulls out 3 records:

- Jane Doe, a non-Employee who is pulled from `PersonResource`.
- John Doe, an Employee who does not exist in `PersonResource` so is pulled from `EmployeeResource`.
- Hank Doe, an Employee who exists in `PersonResource` so is pulled from there.

I've previously done this straight from the Django models, making two separate calls and then combining them with a simple loop.  I'm now attempting to make query from AngularJS, via an `$http` call, and would like to do it in a single call is possible.

How can I make a single `$http` request to Tastypie and have it pull from two resources?

Comment: The answer strongly depends on how would you like to use the data later on. You are about to create a queryset that has two different base models, or is there any inheritance involved between `Person` and `Employee`?

Comment: They have two different base models.  For this instance I only care about a few fields in each, which are in both but might have different field names.

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution would be to create a separate resource with particular view that contains the functionality you need. The union could be done using raw SQL, and the list of results would be then handled by the view itself. The advantage of this over custom `get_queryset` is that the solution is stand-alone and doesn't require hacking other tastypie methods to work with objects that definetly do not quack like a django query set.